# sql query in Rails where value IS BLANK (0 or nil)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

In Rails there is the method item.property.blank? which is true for property being "0" or nil or whitespace.

How can I make an sql query to check if a value is blank?

I now have:

```
Item.where("name = 'Testname' AND property <> '1'")
```

which shows me all items with name = 'Testname' and property = '0', but not those with property = nil (not defined).

How should my sql query be to be equivalent to

```
Item.where("name = 'Testname' AND property IS BLANK")
```

so that all items with property = '0' and property = nil are included to the search results?

Comment: what is **nil** ? it is some ruby specific stuff? You did you mean `NULL`?

Comment: Ah yes, this might be a ruby thing (I only code in ruby). Nil is any completely absent entry (no value has yet been defined) in the database, so literally nothing. E.g. "0" is not nil since 0 is already a value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Item.where("property IN ('0','') OR property IS NULL")
```

or more exactly...

```
Item.where("name = 'Testname' AND (property IN ('0','') OR property IS NULL)")
```

Comment: Thanks, that was almost the solution, just a small change: Item.where("name = 'Testname' AND (property IN ('0','') OR property IS NULL)")

Comment: IN queries generally are not as efficient if i'm not mistaken. The correct way to handle this would be to ensure your values in the database can either be NULL or NOT NULL, nothing else in between. The problem with Rails is (or at least used to be) that blank values are stored as such, instead of converting them to nil values. This can be solved by the strip_attributes gem.

Answer (score 1):

Without using SQL strings, you can do this:

```rb
Item.where(name: 'Testname', property: [nil, '0', ''])
```

It will produce the SQL query

```sql
SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`
WHERE `items`.`name` = 'Testname'
AND (`items`.`property` IN ('0', '') OR `items`.`property` IS NULL)
```